# Bifurcations in a one-dimensional dynamical system, with two parameters

Tags: dynamical-systems, maple, bifurcation

I am given the following dynamical system:

$x'=  -(x^3/(1+x^2))+ \lambda x^2+\mu$

I need to find all bifurcation points when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ vary on the reals, and study their type. (Note: I'm using Maple software to solve this). Please note that this is my very first attempt at solving such an exercise, I have never dealt with dynamical systems before. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

First of all, I wanted to find all non-hyperbolic equilibrium points of the system, that is, if $f = -(x^3/(1+x^2))+ \lambda x^2+\mu $,

$\begin{cases} f(x,\lambda,\mu)=0 \\ \partial f/ \partial x \ f (x,\lambda, \mu) = 0 \end{cases}$

For some reason, Maple (a software I am not too familiar with, but I am required to use that) does not give me explicit solutions for this system. It actually just doesn't compute anything.

So, I have tried a sightly different approach, as done in [this example by Hale-Kocak](https://books.google.it/books?id=xWLdBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false). By solving the second equation with respect to $\lambda$ (parameter $\mu$ vanishes after derivating), I get

$\lambda = (1/2)x(x^2+3)/(x^2+1)^2$

And by substituting in the first one, solving with respect to $\mu$,

$\mu = (1/2)x^3(x^2-1)/(x^2+1)^2$

.. and at this point I'm stuck again. I should get the relation between $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as they have done with parameters $c$ and $d$ in their example, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Any hint is welcome. I'm in serious need of ideas on how to start solving this.

Comment: It's an assignement I have been given. I don't know if it's taken from somewhere or invented by the teacher.

Comment: You mean.. fixing the value of one paramater and study what happens by varying the other? Isn't there the risk to miss some of the bifurcation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you tried by using Maple's **solve** command. That doesn't work very well when the number of equations is different from the number of variables being solved for. The command to use in this case is **eliminate**.

```
f:= -(x^3/(1+x^2))+lambda*x^2+mu:
eliminate({f = 0, diff(f,x) = 0}, {x});
```

This will return a list of two sets. The first contains an equation that expresses $x$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $\mu$. The second contains an expression which when equated to $0$ expresses the relationship *between* $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Since this relationship is provided in factored form, you can immediately see that $\mu=0$ is a special case. The other factor is a polynomial fifth-degree in $\lambda$ and fourth-degree in $\mu$. I'll call it **lu**. I believe that solving **lu** for one of its variables will add great complexity to your work while not giving much benefit. Instead, we can study a bivariate polynomial in great detail without explicitly solving it. In particular, it can be plotted with **plots:-implicitplot** or **algcurves:-plot_real_curve** and some further analysis can be done with other tools in the **algcurves** package.

Please note that I don't know much about analyzing iterative maps. I'm providing this Answer because I know a great deal about Maple.

For plotting the bifurcations in Maple 2016, check out the new **IterativeMaps** package. This produces plots of far superior detail and color than the other Maple plotting commands.

Comment: So, I should use the eliminate command, consider the second expression I get from that and use solve(expr($\lambda$, $\mu$)=0), right? This provides me the relation between the two parameters. Then I can continue my study by drawing the graph in the $(\lambda, \mu)$ plane of such relation, and try to check what happens in the various regions. Is this correct?

Comment: I expanded my Answer above to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Carl.By studying the case $\mu = 0$ first, I have obtained that the origin in an equilibrium point for all values of $\lambda$, and that the other values of $\lambda$ where the behaviour changes are $-1/2, 1/2, 13/25$. I am trying to use the IterativeMaps package to plot my results, but I don't quite get what I'm looking for. I'm using  https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=IterativeMaps/Bifurcation as an example. Code is $Map := Bifurcation([x], [-x^3/(x^2+1)+r*x^2], [.5], -1/2, 13/25)$. I get a wierd image. Something wrong?

Comment: I have tried many different parameter values in that code, both for $r$ and $x$, but I still don't get a significant picture. Rest of the code is exactly like in the above example.

Edit: forgot to mention that I get the following: Error, invalid terms in product: 1 .. 500

Comment: So, you're trying to plot the $\mu=0$ case. My guess is that nothing interesting happens in that case. I tried with $\mu=1$, and I got a plot that showed some bifurcation, nothing spectacular: **Bifurcation([x], [-x^3/(x^2+1)+r*x^2+1], [.5], -1, 1)**.

Comment: Please show the exact code that led to that error message.

Comment: `Map := Bifurcation([x], [-x^3/(x^2+1)+r*x^2], [.5], -1/2, 13/25); 

ArrayTools:-Dimensions(Map)

ColouringProcedures:-HueToRGB(Map); 

Embed(Map)`

Comment: I can't regenerate the error message, and I don't know what packages you have loaded. But, anyway, this is all you need: **Map:= IterativeMaps:-Bifurcation([x], [-x^3/(x^2+1)+r*x^2], [.5], -1/2, 13/25); 
ImageTools:-Embed(Map);**